# 404 Angular Modules in Visual Studio 2017 MVC 5 and Angular 2 integration

Tags: asp.net, angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm trying to configure Angular 2 and Asp.Net MVC 5 using Visual Studio and everything was okay til I decide to add new node modules.

What is the correct configuration when using MVC 5 and Angular 2 com build the node modules during dev enviroment? Should I change the build process to Webpack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer! Using angular with Visual Studio you will need to implement webpack configuration.

https://medium.com/@jonjam/combining-webpack-with-asp-net-mvc-5-a5bd07c49d0b